# How does XCEP policy (XML) define SubjectType for User or Computer constraint?

Tags: windows, certificate, certificate-authority, wcf

We've developed our own implementation of a XCEP/CES WCF service that uses a combination of our certificate management solution and the Microsoft CA to issue the certificates. The standard XCEP XML definition is used (same as the standard Microsoft XCEP/CES WCF service). We use the same WSDL for the WCF service. This works fine for CEP and CES.

Now, we extended the software to use a different Certificate Authority (not Microsoft). The new CA is GlobalSign which has its own certificate template definition and settings (different than the MS CA certificate template settings). The CEP policy service works fine and creates the policy definition in compliance with the CEP XML policy structure, but we have one issue left.

How does XCEP policy define the SubjectType, meaning whether the policy (certificate template) is targeted for users or computers? At the moment, the clients interpret them as user templates and we do not see a property (or basic constraint extension) where we could define a target type "Computer".

Only option we see is an extension called "Certificate Template" extension:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkhU1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is determined by `generalFlags` datum in `Attributes` element ([[MS-XCEP] §3.1.4.1.3.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-xcep/cd22d3a0-f469-4a44-95ed-d10ce4dc2063)). This datum is an a bitwise enumeration of `PKI-Certificate-Template.flags` DS attribute values ([[MS-CRTD] §2.4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-crtd/6cc7eb79-3e84-477a-b398-b0ff2b68a6c0)).

- If datum value has bit `CT_FLAG_MACHINE_TYPE` set, then subject type is computer.
- If datum value has bit `CT_FLAG_IS_CA`, then subject type is CA.
- If both bits are not set, then subject type is user.

Comment: Thank you very much! This flag is exactly what we're looking for.